# Why didn't Sidney trust Randy?

Tags: plot-explanation, scream

During the party at Stu's house toward the end of [Scream (1996)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117571/?ref_=nv_sr_2), the ghost face killer starts to attack. Sidney ends up outside and in the news van with Gale's camera man.

A bit later she is running back into the house (after Gale runs off the road) and when she gets to the porch, Randy runs up limping yelling that they need to get to safety. Sidney basically tells him to f- off as if she doesn't trust him.

Why does she do this? When she was in the news van, her and the camera man watched the ghost face killer sneak up on Randy while he was in the house watching the movie so she clearly saw that he was not the killer.

Why doesn't she trust him and let him in the house with her?

Comment: What happens in the movie that tells her they aren't working together and that only one of them could be the killer?

Comment: It's assumed throughout the movie that there is only a single killer. Only at the end do we know there are two. But, maybe she got freaked that the killer didn't bother Randy when she was watching him on the video. Maybe that spooked her into thinking something was up.

Answer (score 5):

To quote the exchange (from the [Scream Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Scream.html)):

> **RANDY:**  Jesus, Sid. We gotta get out of here.
>
> **Sidney throws the gun forward.**
>
> **SIDNEY:** Stop. Right there.
>
> **RANDY**:  Don't shoot. It's me.
>
> **SIDNEY**: Don't come any closer.
>
> **RANDY**:  Listen to me, Sid. I found Tatum. She's
>           dead, she's been killed...I think Stu did
>           it.
>
> **He takes a step forward when another VOICE SPEAKS UP.**
>
> **VOICE**: Don't believe him, Sid.
>
> **Sidney spins around to see Stu moving up the walk.**
>
> **STU**: He's lying. He killed Tatum. And Billy.
>
> **Stu moves closer to Sidney.**
>
> **SIDNEY**: Stay away.
>
> **She aims the gun in his direction.**
>
> **STU**:  His movie nut mind has snapped, Sid.
>           He's gone psycho.
>
> **RANDY**:  Don't listen to him. It's him. He's the
>           one.
>
> **STU**:  Come on, Sid. Give me the gun.
>
> **RANDY**: No, Sid.
>
> **SIDNEY**: Fuck you both.

So at this stage in the movie, Sid has witnessed her boyfriend (seemingly!) being killed, Kenny killed, a host of other deaths and terror is gripping her.

Then, in the midst of it, two of her friends, either one of which fits the profile of killer perfectly, show up and tell her to give them her gun. She realises it's a choice between trusting one of them and making the wrong choice or trusting herself and her own instincts. She chooses to do that and shuts them both out of the house, keeping the gun for herself.

Your point is very valid though. She certainly saw the killer in the house. But it's highly unlikely she was thinking logically at this point, given all that had happened.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the conclusion I came up with as well.

Comment: Actually, I've amended my answer. See the edit - is that not true?

Comment: She is watching the screen because the camera man says something like, "Oh no, get out of there kid!" and then he opens the door and remembers the 30 second delay. As soon as she gets into the van, she is looking at the screen. I'm looking for the scene to see if you're right though

Comment: Yeah, just changed my answer again once I realised that. Oops! Alas, I think panic got the better of her unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, at this point *Sydney* was really down with her nerves. She had many traumatic experiences in short succession and has just been (and still was) running for her life. So she was in a pretty run down and panicking constitution and I think at this point she didn't trust *anyone*, no matter if she really had any proper reasons to do so.

Add to this, that she saw *Randy* just at the edge of being killed by the killer (on the surveillance video), which he then magically wasn't and the fact that *Randy* in his role as kind of a horror movie nerd always made a good suspect. It is true that *Randy* sure wasn't the same person that aproached him on the video, but maybe she already took into consideration that it could be more than one (if she even considered so much at all, as written above).